# How to resize images larger than 1000px to 50% using mogrify

Tags: image-processing

I am on Ubuntu and using the following command: `find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 -r mogrify -resize 50%`. 
How can I resize only images that are larger 1000px and leave alone the images that are less than 1000px.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may need to do the same thing I requested,

you can check the solutions offered on ImageMagick User forum by Snibgo and fmw42 [Mogrify resize to 50 percent images larger than 800px](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=24872&p=107245#p107245)